# Advantage to using a Window instead of a Dialog

Tags: c++, windows, api, dialog, window

Can someone tell me the advantages to filling a `WNDCLASS` structure and calling `CreateWindow` instead of just using a Dialog Box?
Using a Dialog Box for the main GUI window is much easier since I can create it using a resource editor.

So could someone give me a reason why I would want to create a Window instead of a Dialog for the main window of the GUI?

Comment: I think proper windows offer a much richer set of semantics than a dialog box. That said, I think all of the old Visual Basic was essentially just creating a dialog box, so you can probably get quite far with that approach.

Comment: Who says there is an advantage?

Comment: Dialogs *are* windows. Their windows class is [WC_DIALOG](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/31/733521.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dialog is a particular case of a window that is tailored to manage child controls (that are themselves other type of windows).

A window created with its own winclass is a window that has to have its own semantics in using inputs and producing its own output.

Typically is a control that doesn't exist yet.

That's not a matter of advantages, simply is the way to do another not existing thing, not entirely based on the reuse of existing others.